# Response time difference in Jmeter and Postman

Tags: performance, api, jmeter, postman, performance-testing

I'm trying to test an API Get method when I run the same API for 1000 records in postman the response time is 4 seconds (installed postman in windows 7 and ran the test), whereas in JMeter it is taking 22 seconds, any idea what might be the reason for this?

Steps followed for JMeter run:

1. GUI mode
2. Non-GUI mode

Both Postman and JMeter are in same system/network.

Below is the Jmeter result:

```
Thread Name: Test/TestAPI 1-1
Sample Start: 2018-05-22 17:15:00 IST
Load time: **21406** // this is the issue , same in postman taking only 4712 ms
Connect Time: 425
Latency: 1990
Size in bytes: 3962439
Sent bytes:1130
Headers size in bytes: 175
Body size in bytes: 3962264
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 200
Response message: OK
Response headers:HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
api-supported-versions: 1
Date: Tue, 22 May 2018 11:45:06 GMT
Content-Length: 3958179
Server: Web Server
HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: application/json; charset=utf-8
DataEncoding: utf-8
```

Post Man Results:

```
api-supported-versions →1
content-encoding →gzip
content-type →application/json; charset=utf-8
date →Tue, 22 May 2018 12:00:11 GMT
server →Web Server
transfer-encoding →chunked
vary →Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: can you give more details,also what does JMeter results show?

Comment: what kind of information shall i provide ? please let me know. Jmeter results show 200 OK with and average time 22112 ms (22 seconds) , if i run the same API the postman showing as 4720 ms(4 seconds). Jmeter version 4.0

Comment: What happens when you set in JMeter ramp up period (in Thread Group) as 1000 ?

Comment: Still taking almost same seconds , i.e 28 seconds now , Number of threads: 1 , Ramp Up : 1000 , loop count :1  , My system configuration : i3 CPU @ 3.7 GH 8 GB Ram , 64 bit

Comment: you are missing header `content-encoding` in JMeter

Comment: So shall i add gzip in content encoding of jmeter ? if i do that am getting below error : Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: gzip

Comment: see http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean

Comment: I have added Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate  in header manager , now time reduced to 8 seconds , Thanks for the suggestion :) and is there anything we can still reduce the time which is equal to postman results ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to compare similar request. In your case at least 1 header is missing. Add to JMeter's HTTP Header `Accept-Encoding    gzip,deflate`

Follow JMeter's [Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) to get the best performance, the main one is not to use listeners:

> Use non-GUI mode: jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l test.jtl
>
> Use as few Listeners as possible; if using the -l flag as above they can all be deleted or disabled.